# Yii Framework: relation returns NULL

Tags: yii, frameworks

I have trouble with relations in my application. I have following **tables:**

post:

> id | title | text | label
>
> 1  | lala  | lala |  1

post_label:

> id | name
>
> 1  | security
>
> 2 | other

two **models:** Post, PostLabel

and **relation** in post model:

> 'postLabel' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'PostLabel', 'id'),

When i use this:

> $model=$this->loadModel('Post',1);
>
> var_dump($model->postLabel);

it returns NULL, but when i use:

> $model=$this->loadModel('Post',1);
>
> var_dump($model->title);

it returns 'lala'

Where I made mistake?

Edit: I see in sql query there is using post id, but not label id. How to change this?

Comment: What returns NULL? Is `$model` null or `$model->postLabel`? Please post the resulting SQL query.

Comment: $model->postLabel return NULL. Query: "SELECT `postLabel`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `postLabel`.`name` AS `t1_c1` FROM `post_label` `postLabel` WHERE (`postLabel`.`id`='1009')`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it sounds counter intuitive (it took me some time to get used to), but you actually need to use BELONGS_TO relation, not HAS_ONE.

Check this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/

> **KEY POINT**: A BELONGS_TO relation says that a field in this model points to the primary key in another model; in this case, the current model owns the linking field.
>
> **KEY POINT**: A HAS_ONE relation says that some other model has a linking field pointing to this model's primary key; in this case, the related model owns the linking field.

Because *label* is key in this (**Post**) model that points to primary key of another (**PostLabel**) model, you need to use BELONGS_TO relation.

So your relation definition should look like this:

```
'postLabel' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PostLabel', 'label')
```

Comment: That's what I meant! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your relation uses the wrong foreign key column. It must be `label`:

```
'postLabel' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'PostLabel', 'label'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any table or attribute to make the join between the 2 tables!

Post has only `id | title | text | category` and post_label `id | name` but how do we know what label belongs to what post?!

In post_label You should have a field like `post_id` and in your relations you'll declare

```
'postLabel' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'PostLabel', 'post_id'),
```

Then you'll get something!

Comment: Sorry I write 'category' but I meant 'label'. I want join 'label'(from post) with 'id'(from post_label). Is a way to do this?